# Plotting in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to simulate the first order differential equation using the fourth order [Runge-Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), but I am having problems plotting it.

```
#simulation of ode using 4th order rk method  dy/dx=-2y+1.3e^-x,y(0)=5,h=0.01 from sympy import*
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h=0.01;
ti=0;
x=0;
n=0;
y=5;
def f(x,y):
    return 1.3*math.exp(-x)-2*y


while x < 10:

    k1=f(x,5);
    k2=f(x+h/2,y+(h/2)* k1);
    k3=f(x+h/2,y+(h/2)* k2);
    k4=f(x+h,y+h*k3);
    y=y+h/6*(k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4);
    x=x+h;
    plt.plot(x,y);
```

I know that the problem is because of updating the x,y values every time the loop runs, but can somebody explain how to plot all the values of (x,y)?

Comment: Try to gather (x,y) values in a list (or two lists, depends on your plot). Then, plot the data list once.

Comment: let me try @MichaelHoff

Comment: For example, [this tutorial](https://bespokeblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/basic-data-plotting-with-matplotlib-part-2-lines-points-formatting/) shows the use of data points together with `matplotlib.plot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, you can create two lists to store `x` and `y` values and plot it after the `while` loop:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h=0.01;
ti=0;
x=0;
n=0;
y=5;
def f(x,y):
    return 1.3*math.exp(-x)-2*y

xs = [x]       # <<<
ys = [y]       # <<<
while x < 10:

    k1=f(x,5);
    k2=f(x+h/2,y+(h/2)* k1);
    k3=f(x+h/2,y+(h/2)* k2);
    k4=f(x+h,y+h*k3);
    y=y+h/6*(k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4);
    x=x+h;
    xs.append(x)    # <<<
    ys.append(y)    # <<<

plt.plot(xs,ys);
```

[image]

Comment: This is a minor comment but you might want to also add the initial condition to your x/y-values.

Comment: @pathoren Considering the amount of points OP has, it doesn't make much difference to add another point, but good catch!

Comment: Add this line on the top of your script: `%matplotlib inline` if you are using `ipython/jupyter notebook`.

Answer (score 0):

Another source for wrong results is the first line in the RK4 loop. Instead of

```
    k1=f(x,5);
```

use

```
    k1=f(x,y);
```

since the value of `y` does not stay constant at the initial value.